# How to find the time complexity of the following recursive code?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity

How to derive the runtime complexity of the following program?

```
public void function(int n){
   if(n==1) return;
   for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     function(i)
   }
}

function(4);
```

What i understand is,

```
T(n) = n(T(n-1));
T(n-1) = (n-1)(T(n-2))
T(n-2) = (n-2)(T(n-2))
```

After replacing `n(T(n-1))` with subsequent expansion,

```
T(n) = n((n-1)((n-2)(T(n-2))))
```

Which is essentially nothing but

```
n*(n-1)*(n-2)...1 = n!
```

However, in different posts, i see that this is `2^n` not `n!`.
Can anyone please explain me if I have missed anything?

Comment: What you've posted is linear.

Comment: Are you sure the code `function(1)` should not be `function(n - 1)` ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. Have updated the code. please take a look now.

Comment: Can you point to a post that says that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`T(n) = n T(n-1)` would indeed be `O(N!)` - but it is the **wrong** recurrence relation for `function`.

The loop runs from `i = 0` to `i = n-1`, which means that the recursive calls are `function(0)`, `function(1)`, `function(2)` ... , `function(n-1)`. Hence the recurrence relation is:

```
T(n) = T(0) + T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(n-1)
```

There's a neat trick to help you solve this. Consider the terms in `T(n-1)` and write the expansion alongside that of `T(n)`:

```
T(n)   = T(0) + T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(n-3) + T(n-2) + T(n-1)
                                                      ------
T(n-1) = T(0) + T(1) + T(2) + ... + T(n-3) + T(n-2)
```

See where this is going? Subtract one from the other and only the underlined term `T(n-1)` is left:

```
T(n) - T(n-1) = T(n-1)
T(n) = 2 T(n-1)
```

This alternative form of the recurrence is now solvable in the same manner as before:

```
T(n) = 2^2 T(n-2)
     = 2^3 T(n-3)
     = 2^4 T(n-4)
     = ...
     = O(2^n)
```

q.e.d.

Comment: Perfect. Couldn't expect a better explanation. Thank you again.